# Help me pronounce single "r"

Tags: pronunciación

I've recently started studying Spanish (Latin American) with Rosetta Stone. I think I'm doing trilled *r*'s right but I'm not sure if I'm doing single *r*'s right. Are they supposed to have a single trill, or no trill? Please help me learn how to pronounce a single *r*.

Comment: The pronunciation of the *r* can vary regionally, and by the specific word.  In some cases, it's almost an English *d* sound, in others it's closer to an English *r*.  And there are times when it is trilled, depending on its location in the word.  Your best bet to pick up the subtleties will probably be to listen to some native speakers.  If you don't have this option in person, perhaps on YouTube.

Comment: @Flimzy English /d/ or /r/? Isn't it generally an alveolar tap? I'm talking about a*r*ticula*r*, not "el *r*atón *r*oyó".

Comment: What @Artefacto said, plus:  A Word inicial "r" is pronounced like a trilled "rr".  I can't think of any exceptions to this, off the top of my head.

Answer (score 5):

Encontré algunos videos en Youtube que explica los detalles de la pronunciación de la letra R, con ejemplos:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sz8tNXuX0nA

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYUMz2vY3c8

Comment: @Dan, welcome to the StackExchange network, I'm glad to help, if my answer was helpful, maybe you want to up-vote it and maybe [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 4):

I think is very similar to the english 'r' but you have to put your tongue closer to the teeth. You can also try to understand this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_tap

Comment: It's very important the tongue briefly touches the alveolar ridge. In Portuguese, we have the same sound and the easiest way to tell an English accent is the way the intervocalic -r- is incorrectly pronounced. The sound is close to the alveolar trill (the other rhotic sound in Spanish), but the tongue only vibrates a single cycle.

Comment: +1 for the link. Very nice

Answer (score 1):

In my experience (4 years study of Castilian Spanish, 7 years of Latin Spanish conversations [mostly Colombian style]), for the Latin style Spanish at least, the single trill is what I use and everyone understands it well and I haven't had anyone correct me yet.

It *is* similar to the English 'r' only in the constant sound the 'r' produces. The English 'r' starts with the lips together and pointing out while pulling them back and widening them, while a single trill is more like a single roll of the tongue from top to bottom while emitting a very quick English 'r' type of sound.

Also, while you don't mention it, I think it's worthwhile pointing out that a single 'r' at the beginning of a word is rolled like a double 'rr' ([alveolar trill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_trill)). However, I find that a single 'r' at the end of a word is like a whispering trill with a slight English 'r' sound. In study, they might make you have the 'r' at the end be just like a strong double 'rr', but in actual conversation with Latin people you will probably never hear it emphasized like that (at least I haven't yet).

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The closest sound in American English is a soft d or t. Think about really enunciating a strong d or t and then do the opposite. In both sounds your tongue taps the roof of your mouth. Whereas the tongue touches quite close to your teeth for a t sound, try moving it back towards the middle of the roof of your mouth. Tap your tongue softly as you make the sound, touching with most of the front of your tongue, not just the tip.

It's not too dissimilar to the soft d and t sounds in the following American English words:

> The tt in gotta or a lotta
>   The t in water
>   The dd in muddy
>   The d in modern

Try saying the following Spanish words with this in mind, keeping the r's (d's) soft:

> Say cara like cahdah
>   Say para like pahdah
>   Say oro like ohdoh

That's always worked really well for me. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

[This is an absolutely fabulous site](http://www.uiowa.edu/~acadtech/phonetics/spanish/frameset.html) that not only explains the various elements of the mouth (articulatory anatomy) and how they contribute to speech, but also provides animations, audio and video.  It is available in English, German, and Spanish.
It's a fun site to spend some time browsing but you will need Flash to use it.

Comment: Single "r" (soft) is under "vibrantes", [ɾ], the first phonema of the link.

Answer (score 1):

Say "pot of tea" out loud. Gradually say it quicker and quicker, maintaining pronunciation as best as possible. You will notice that the 't' from 'pot' and sounds less and less like a 't' and more like the Spanish single 'r'.

Actually, as you say it faster and faster, it sounds more and more like the Spanish "para ti" ("for you").

Comment: Ha it had the same effect for me. And still, no one brought me even a CUP of tea....

Answer (score 0):

I have some questions to ask you.I have tried learning Spanish on some websites, by some language learning programs and I've noticed that:
-The single "r"sound: They taught me that it's only trilled when it's at the beginning of a word or after letters l,n,s  and it sounds like an English "d" in most of situations but I heard that it's also slightly trilled in the word "comer" or "tarde".
-The "v" sound: it sounds like a "b" but I still hear some native speakers pronounce as an English "v" like the word "bienvenidos" or "verdad".
- The "d"sound: it sounds like an English "d" but in the word "nada", I find it 
does not. But I do not hear the sound clearly so I can't repeat it.
I hope you will explain to me how it sounds soon. Or if i don't hear the sound of any of three letters above incorrectly, please tell me.
Thank you very much. Always hope for answers from native speakers.

Comment: Hey welcome to Spanish SE. Try to improve the formatting of your answers so their readability improves. Read the FAQ for more info. Remember that referencing your answers is crucial.